# How to handle S3 events inside a Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster that runs on AWS EKS,
now I want to handle S3 object creation events in a pod,
like I would with AWS Lambda.

How can I handle S3 events from inside a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Use [SQS or SNS notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), and write code that subscribes to a queue and hendles these events.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but I can assume you are looking for something similar to K8s jobs? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/ 
let me know if this is the direction and I could provide more guide in this

Comment: I have a Lambda triggerd by uploads to an S3 bucket and now I want to replace the Lambda with a container running inside a K8s cluster hosted on EKS.

Comment: @K.. what solution did you used? S3 -> lambda -> eks ?

Answer (score 1):

S3 events can only be sent to [SQS, SNS or Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html). So any S3 -> K8s integration will have to use those event destinations. I can think of couple of options to trigger K8s `Job`s using S3 events (I'm assuming the K8s cluster is EKS)

**Option 1:**

1. S3 events are sent to a SQS queue
2. K8s `Job` polling the SQS queue -- the `Job` will have a `ServiceAccount` mapped to an IAM role which can read from SQS

**Option 2:**

1. S3 events trigger a Lambda function
2. This Lambda function uses [container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) which has `kubectl`/`helm` installed.
3. Lambda function's IAM role will be mapped to a [K8s `Role`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)
4. Lambda function runs some code/script that creates following when invoked (using `kubectl`/`helm`)

   a. A `ConfigMap` with the event information is

   b. A `Job` that takes the `ConfigMap` name/label as a parameter or environment variable